# Can I define an alias in bashrc in an incremental way?

Tags: bash, alias, recursive

In my .bashrc, at the moment, I have something like this:

```bsh
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    # ...
    alias ls='ls --color=auto -F'
    # ...
fi

# xxx
alias ll='ls -AltF'
```

Now let's say that I want `ls` to use the `--group-directrories-first` option too.

What I'd do is adding the line `alias ls='ls --group-directrories-first'` at `# xxx`.

However, this replaces the `alias` in full, so that the options `--color=auto` and `-F` are gone.

How can I address this?

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you just use one alias with all the options you need? `alias ls='ls --color=auto -F --group-directrories-first`. Why would you need to define them incrementally?

Comment: @terdon likely because of the conditional logic. This is possibly a simplified example.

Comment: @terdon, there's an `if` there at the top. I don't want the alias to have `--color=auto` if that conditional expression is false.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to keep track of the options in a variable:

```bsh
lsOptions=""

if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    lsOptions="$lsOptions --color=auto -F"
fi

if [ something else]; then
    lsOptions="$lsOptions --group-directories-first"
fi

## After all the ifs have been evaluated
alias ls="ls $lsOptions"
```